# How to subtract min max date's values and calculate with different group by in SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, group-by, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to populate the right table from the left one.

[image]

I was trying to get min and max (month) by `group by brand` and then get its value according to the month.

```sql
select
    brand
   ,month
   ,value
from table 
where month=max(month) or month=min(month)
```

I'm not sure how to do it in an efficient way.

Comment: you have a month as "march" and the rest as 3 characters in the input data? that's just bad design / entry.

Comment: Where does that /10 and /500 come from in the growth_date column?

Comment: Also, the calculation, is it supposed to be `10-(100/10)` or `(10-100)/10` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid joins, you can calculate the `min` and `max` using window function.

```python
spark.sql('''
    select brand, mth, val from (
        select *,
            min(mth_int) over (partition by brand) as min_mth_int,
            max(mth_int) over (partition by brand) as max_mth_int
        from(
            select *, month(coalesce(to_date(initcap(mth), "MMM"), to_date(initcap(mth), "MMMM"))) as mth_int
            from data))
    where mth_int=min_mth_int or mth_int=max_mth_int
    '''). \
    show()

# +-----+-----+----+
# |brand|  mth| val|
# +-----+-----+----+
# |    a|  jan| 500|
# |    a|march|1000|
# +-----+-----+----+
```

*P.S. the `month()` function used here will not be available in Redshift, and you can use its `extract()` function to get the month. There might be a slight difference in Redshift's `to_date()` function as well.*

```python
spark.sql('''
    select *, (max_mth_val - min_mth_val) / max_mth_val as growth_rate
    from (
        select brand, 
            max(case when mth_int = min_mth_int then val end) as min_mth_val,
            max(case when mth_int = max_mth_int then val end) as max_mth_val
        from (
            select *,
                min(mth_int) over (partition by brand) as min_mth_int,
                max(mth_int) over (partition by brand) as max_mth_int
            from(
                select *, month(coalesce(to_date(initcap(mth), "MMM"), to_date(initcap(mth), "MMMM"))) as mth_int
                from data))
        where mth_int=min_mth_int or mth_int=max_mth_int
        group by brand)
    '''). \
    show()
    
# +-----+-----------+-----------+-----------+
# |brand|min_mth_val|max_mth_val|growth_rate|
# +-----+-----------+-----------+-----------+
# |    a|        500|       1000|        0.5|
# +-----+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to have `month` as an integer.

[image]

After that you need to join two times the same table with itself in order to get the value for the min and max months by brand.

```
    select a.*, b.value as value_max_month, c.value as value_min_month
    from(
      select 
      brand, max(month) as max_month, min(month) as min_month 
      from table1
      group by brand) as a 
    left join table1 as b on a.max_month = b.month and a.brand = b.brand
    left join table1 as c on a.min_month = c.month and a.brand = c.brand
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following will return you parts of what you're looking for.

Input:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW table
    AS VALUES
        (('a', 1, 500)),
        (('a', 2, 300)),
        (('a', 3, 1000)),
        (('bb', 1, 100)),
        (('bb', 2, 50)),
        (('bb', 3, 10))
    AS tab(brand, month, value)
```

Script:

```sql
SELECT brand, min_by (value, month) min, max_by(value, month) max
FROM table
GROUP BY brand
```

```
+-----+---+----+
|brand|min| max|
+-----+---+----+
|    a|500|1000|
|   bb|100|  10|
+-----+---+----+
```